# git push complete and separate branch to remote repository

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a Git Server...

My Partner created a new branch....

```
cd C:\profaNew\ProjectosJava
git checkout -b diana
git branch
git add .
git commit -m "Nuevo Proyecto Base"
git remote add origin git@192.168.5.200:/srv/git/project.git
git push -u origin diana
```

Now in my machine, I hope view her branch, But I got:

```
C:\Migracion\project (master -> origin)
λ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master

C:\Migracion\project (master -> origin)
λ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master

C:\Migracion\project (master -> origin)
```

**How Can I get download the branch `diana`?**

Comment: thank you... Now I can see her branch, Now I need to download her branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you `git fetch` beforehand to get updated refs for remote branches? If yes then the new diana branch *should* appear in the fetch output, and afterwards also in your `git branch -a` and `git branch -r` commands output.